# Mac Docker Bulk Insert Into MS-SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, docker, macos

On my Mac I’ve installed an instance of MS-SQL server in a Docker container. I’m able to connect to it using Azure Data Studio and can create tables, write queries, etc. without any problem. I’m now trying seed a table doing a bulk insert from an external csv file. I’ve copied the files to the Docker container as described in this post: [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241082/macos-docker-cannot-bulk-load-the-file-path-does-not-exist-or-you-dont-have)

When I try to run the bulk insert, I get the following error:

`Cannot bulk load because the file "/CountryErrors.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)`

I’m not very familiar with Linux and the CLI, but I’m guessing the permissions are incorrect. I’m not sure how to or what to change them to?

```
-rw-r--r--   1  501 dialout         0 Jul 18 23:51 CountryErrors.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1  501 dialout       478 Sep  7  2019 CountryFormat.fmt
-rw-rw-rw-   1  501 dialout     11816 Sep  7  2019 CountrySeed.csv
```

Relevant SQL code:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[#CountryTEMP]
    FROM '/CountrySeed.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FORMATFILE = '/CountryFormat.fmt',
    ERRORFILE = '/CountryErrors.txt'
    )
```

Comment: The permissions for CountryErrors.txt are set to 644 (readwrite / read / read). Presumably, they should be set to 664 (same as CountryFormat.fmt) or 666 (CountrySeed.csv).

To achieve this, run
```chmod 666 /CountryErrors.txt```

Comment: When I try to run `chmod 666 /CountryErrors.txt`, I get the error `chmod: changing permissions of '/CountryErrors.txt': Operation not permitted`

Comment: The "501" in the ls output might indicate a user mapping problem (usually, you should see the username; the uid 501 might be missing and therefore cannot be mapped to a valid user).

How did you set up the container and the files in / ? Is / mounted from the host filesystem? And what's the output of ```id``` when you run it in the container?

Comment: I copied the files to the container using `docker cp /path/to/file/CountrySeed.csv 1f677bbf9a44:/`

When I run `id`, I get: `uid=10001(mssql) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

Comment: Why are the owner:group set to 501:dialout? The SQL Server service inside Docker containers is usually executing with the `mssql` user and the `/var/opt/mssql` directories and files it uses are set to mssql:mssql (2019) or mssql:root (2022). When you `docker cp` files into a container that task is executing under the Docker backend's authority. If your Docker container were named `0ecd3ebd8c09`, for example, have you tried following up your `docker cp` command with `docker exec -u 0 0ecd3ebd8c09 bash -c "chown mssql:mssql /Country*.*"` This effectively executes the `chown` command as root.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, when I try to run the command you suggested, I get: `chown: invalid group: 'mssql:mssql'`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, sorry my mistake, I needed to use `mssql:root` for SQL Server 2022. But I still get the same error after executing the command.

Comment: What is shown if you `ls -la /Country*.*` inside the container now? (Edit your question to show the new output.)